# Compare date and month in sql server for alert system

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an a table with two columns birthday and anniversary. I want to get alerts about birthdays and anniversaries between a 7 day period of time but, that should not include year (obviously if I include year, it would always be less than the current date). I want to get the alerts 7 days in advance.

That is, the query should compare the birthday and anniversary with the current date and return a list if their birthday or anniversary falls between 7 days of the same month so that it alerts me in advance about the upcoming birthdays and anniversaries.

Comment: Have you constructed any queries..?

Comment: Here is the query I used:

select * from customer where (MONTH(Anniversary)= MONTH(getdate())) OR (MONTH(Birthday)= MONTH(getdate()))

Comment: I want to be more specific about the dates....

I want the dates to be within one week (7 days) of the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the year difference from now to the requested date and then use datediff to calculate the date difference of the result with the requested date.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table
WHERE  DATEDIFF(dd,DATEADD(yyyy,-DATEDIFF(yyyy,Birthday,GETDATE()),GETDATE()),Birthday) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
       OR DATEDIFF(dd,DATEADD(yyyy,-DATEDIFF(yyyy,Anniversary,GETDATE()),GETDATE()),Anniversary) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
```

Comment: Thank you all for your response... Your code helped to a lot extent but your code filters out anyone whose birthday or anniversary lies in the same month. Although, I want to filter out only the records where birthday or anniversary lies within 7 days from the current date so that I get to know in advance about the upcoming birthdays and anniversaries. Remember I need to get alerts only for the upcoming birthdays or anniversaries.

Comment: I will see what is wrong with the same month. Can you be more specific for the rest? Perhaps some sample data would help.

Comment: I saw what you mean. The problem is that negative values are less than 7 that is a positive.... So the requirement would be to be a positive number and less than 7. Check it out and let me know...

Comment: Actually the problem is that your query returns dates wherever the bairthday or anniversary is between 7 days. No matter the year nd month.

the totals no. of records were 14, it returned 7 records with the following dates:

8/24/1992
8/27/1990
6/25/1980

what I want:

8/29/1992, 8/30/2000, 8/31/1980

but not 7/29/1992

Comment: Hi, Can you please add sample data in your initial post (for all to see). And please explain, do you care just for the birthday or for the anniversary as well?

Comment: Thank you jyparask, your query is 100% correct. I checked it with all types of situations and it produced correct output in all the cases. Thank you for patiently answering my question. That comment about unexpected results was for your previous query. The new query works fine. Your answer is the perfect solution I was looking for... Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
  SELECT Name,max(Table .birthdate) 
    FROM  Table group by Table .Name having (datediff(day,max(birthdate),getutcdate())>7 and datediff(day,max(birthdate),getutcdate())<8)
```